# Append UL li with modal pop up

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-modal

I want to list some subjects using ul and li.....
when user click li I want to show subject detail in modal pop up

```
$.each(data, function (i,item) {

 $("#myUL").append('<li  ><a href="#" >' + item.subject + '</a></li>');
//modal with item.detail
}
```

how can I show each subjets detail in pop up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have code example of Bootstrap Modal: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_modal&stacked=h

```
$.each(data, function (i,item) {

 $("#myUL").append('<li  ><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" href="javascript:void(0);" >' + item.subject + '</a></li>');
 var textValue = item.subject;
 $("#myUL").last().click(function() { 
  $(".modal-body p").text(textValue);
});
};
```

I am no jQuery expert but this should work.
You could also do it with global variable changed on click and template string inside modal body paragraph.

EDIT:

Add this inside `<head>` tag

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

And this inside `<body>`:

```
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

CODEPEN example:
https://codepen.io/miroslaw-dubaj/pen/QZjqeQ

Comment: it does not work..click not triggereden...should I add some html or bootrapmodal.js include ?

Comment: Check EDIT section of answer. I also changed code in original answer - data attributes moved to anchor tag. It works as far as I checked.